# HMVC and Clean Architecture

Tags: hmvc, clean-architecture

Actually, I'm trying to make a web application for the hospital in PHP. Which approach would be good?. And also, I heard about Clean Architecture. Is this possible to implement in PHP? What could be directory structure? Thank you.

Comment: If you are asking about clean architecture it's a clear sign you should not make any application for any hospital in a first place. I'm not trying to be rude.

Comment: I have done in a procedural way before 3/4 year ago as FYP Project in PHP. Now, I want to make it in real time. What Framework would be good? Thak you.

Comment: Symfony is most enterprise, Laravel is most hyped, more you can find in Google. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Clean Architecture is an "architecture pattern" which is independent from specific frameworks or programming languages. I successfully used it in C# and F# projects. You can apply it to PHP projects as well. You should probably start reading about the details in Uncle Bobs article: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

The Clean Architecture is not very specific about a project structure - as long as u respect the dependency rule. Nevertheless most projects I saw separate the circles into separate projects.

If you want to read about a more detailed example how you could organize your project pls have a look at my blog post: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Scream/. Other aspects of the CLean architecture are discussed in the series as well.

Comment: Thank you for your precise information and guidance.